# Riak kv leveldb corruption

Tags: erlang, riak, leveldb

We use **riak kv** as backend database in our production erlang application. Today I saw lots of errors in log file of one **riak kv vnodes**.

> {error,  {db_open,  "Corruption : truncated record at end of file"}} 
>   in synctree_leveldb:safe_open/3.

I can see this error for one partition. 
How can I repair the corrupted file? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking RIak KV will self heal, i.e. you might see errors in the log but not experience issues with data loss or bad responses being returned by clients. If you need, or want, to manually repair LevelDB check out the following document:

http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/using/repair-recovery/repairs/#repairing-leveldb